# Difference between C++0x lambdas and operator(), closure and functor

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, closures

I'm confident I get the general gist of the constructs, but I can't see the purpose of them in c++. I have read the previous posts on the topic here on SO and elsewhere, but I fail to see why they should be a new language feature.

The things I would like answered is thusly

- What is the difference between a lambda and a template argument accepting a function/functor.
- Is a closure just a functor with some set object state (scope?)?
- What is the "killer app" for these constructs? or perhaps the typical use case?

Comment: It takes more than 5 pages in the standard in 5.1.2 to describe lambdas. The only way to give brief answer if there is a direct question.

Comment: Herb Sutter's " Lambdas, Lambdas Everywhere" presentation at PDC10 does a very good job of explaining lambdas in C++. Can find the link here: http://herbsutter.com/2010/10/30/pdc-languages-panel-andshortened-lambdas-talk/ or directly http://bit.ly/dcJcXN

Comment: @Eugen Thanks for the links Eugen

Comment: @Eugen Moonlight doesn't seem to handle those videos well. I dont have and windows comp handy at the moment.

Comment: You can download it as PPTX/MP4/WMV from here http://player.microsoftpdc.com/schedule/sessions

Comment: @Eugen The mp4 worked perfectly. +1 for effort.

Comment: Also an important part of that presentation is that, theres not one killer app, but rather the sheer number of examples and applications.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lambdas are really just syntactic sugar for a functor.  You could do it all yourself: defining a new class, making member variables to hold the captured values and references, hooking them up in the constructor, writing `operator()()`, and finally creating an instance and passing it.  Or you could use a lambda that's 1/10 as much code and works the same.

Lambdas which don't capture can be converted to function pointers.  All lambdas can be converted to `std::function`, or get their own unique type which works well in templated algorithms accepting a functor.

Comment: can you have anonymous functors? can functors deduce return type? can functors implicitly capture the context and do lookup like lambdas? can you create functor in place of expression?

Comment: And this is the way I'm teaching functors atm. I really don't worry about the amount of code as it is easy to explain when the topic arises. Also it seems quite elegant in the old style.

Comment: So what is the killer app that made lambdas a part of the language?   1/10 of the code is not a selling point for me.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: Well it is for a lot of people.  Less code means it's easier to find the specific operation, which makes it more readable.  I don't know of any advantage of lambdas except making the source code much terser in most functor situations.  What's the killer advantage of operator overloading (vs overloading named functions)?  Nothing but syntax.

Comment: @Gene: Lambdas aren't anonymous either, they receive a type name from the compiler, it just isn't directly expressible in source code (but `decltype` works).  Functors can capture context, but it's not implicit.  That's part and parcel of "syntactic sugar": less source code for the same result.  And yes functors can deduce return type in C++0x (using the new functional notation `auto operator()( T1 x, T2 y ) -> decltype (x.f(y.g()));`).

Comment: @Ben Voigt Odd expressions with odd symbols are rarely for readability. I appreciate less code.  Also the killer app for overloading operators are obvious + / * for complex and matrix. I cant find the killer app for these, and I would like to.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: But you could write `mult(A, B)` for matrix multiplication, you don't need the overloaded operators, it's just nicer syntax.  Same for lambdas, nicer syntax that doesn't overwhelm your logic in boilerplate functor declaration code.

Comment: @Ben Voig: so are anonymous namespaces receive a unique unaccessible name from compiler, that's what anonymous is all about. `decltype` can be used, it's just a trailing return type, only lambdas can omit return type altogether. and other mentioned things also unique to lambdas.

Comment: I'm just at odds with whats nicer I guess. I always loved c++ since the mid 90's =)

Comment: I can't accept two answers as correct I suppose, I'd really like a thorough answer like this on closures as well.

Comment: @Captain: If you wan't motivating examples, STL on the Visual C++ team (he's Microsoft's resident expert on the Standard Template Library too!) wrote [a nice blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx).

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yes those are convincing.

Comment: @Captain: Closures are lambdas.  Lambdas can be broadly divided into two categories: the `[]` are empty, which creates a stateless functor, or the `[]` have something inside, which creates a closure.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Ok that was concise, and swiftly put all my worries away. Thanks Ben.

Comment: @Gene: I'm not sure what your point is.  Lambdas are syntactic sugar.  They allow you to define functors without explicitly specifying every bit of the functor structure explicitly.  They still act like functors because they evaluate to functors.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - I guess, I disagree with your definition of syntactic sugar, which in my view is something nice, but trivial, and not really important. If lambdas are syntactic sugar, then half of C++ is syntactic sugar as well.

Comment: @Gene Yes but my outset was the 1998 c++ spec which I have grown accustomed to =)

Comment: @Gene: I think that's probably accurate.  Virtual functions are mostly syntactic sugar for a pointer to an array of function pointers (with extra magic for virtual inheritance).  Loops are nothing but syntactic sugar for `goto`.  Templates are mostly just syntactic sugar for writing every single instantiation out the long way.

Comment: Of course, some other features (like access modifiers) interact with these features, which ultimately makes them more than syntactic sugar.  I don't think that's happened with lambdas (yet).

Answer (score 12):

Ok, you're actually asking a bunch of different questions, possibly because you are not fully familiar with terminology.  I'll try to answer all.

What's the difference between a lambda and "operator()"? - Let's reword this to, "What's the difference between a lambda and object with operator()?"

Basically, nothing.  The main difference is that a lambda expression creates a functional object while an object with an operator() IS a functional object.  The end result is similar enough to consider the same though, an entity that can be invoked with the (params) syntax.

What's the difference between a closure and a functor?  This is also rather confused.  Please review this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#C.2B.2B

So, as you can see, a closure is a kind of "functor" that is defined within a scope such that it absorbs the variables available to it within that scope.  In other words, its a function that is built on the fly, during the operation of the program and that building process is parameterized by the runtime values of the scope containing it.  So, in C++ closures are lambdas that use values within the function building the lambda.

What is the difference between a lambda and a template argument accepting a function/functor? - This is again confused.  The difference is that they are nothing alike, really.  A template "argument" accepting a function/functor is already confused wording so I'll assume by "argument" you mean "function", because arguments don't accept anything.  In this case, although a lambda can accept a functor as an argument, it can't be templated, one.  Two, generally the lambda is the one being passed as an argument to a function accepting a functor argument.

Is a closure just a functor with some set object state (scope?)?

As you can see by the above link, no.  In fact, a closure doesn't even have state, really.  A closure is built based UPON the state of some other entity that built it, within that functor though this isn't state, it's the very construction of the object.

What is the "killer app" for these constructs? or perhaps the typical use case?

I'll reword that to, "Why are these things useful?"

Well, in general the ability to treat any object as a function if it has operator() is extremely useful for a whole array of things.  For one, it allows us to extend the behavior of any stdlib algorithm by using either objects or free functions.  It's impossible to inummerate the vast supply of usefulnesses this has.

More specifically speaking of lambda expressions, they simply make this process yet easier.  The limitations imposed by object definitions made the process of using stdlib algorithms slightly inefficient in some cases (from a development use perspective, not program efficiency).  For one thing, at the time at least any object passed as a parameter to a template had to be externally defined.  I believe that's also changing, but still...having to create entire objects just to perform basic things, that only get used in one place, is inconvenient.  Lambda expressions allow that definition to be quite easy, within the scope of the place its being used, etc, etc...

Comment: I really like your answer +1. but the "Well, in general the ability to treat any object as a function if it has operator() is extremely useful" -pretty much brings me back to my original question.

Comment: I think you'll need to point out your original question then because I saw several and gave the best answer I could to all of them.

Comment: It was a three part question and I apologize for that. Your answer gave me good insight. I really appreciate your answer